# split 2-d array based columns to two 2-d array in python by using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, split

i have a 2-d array by 19 rows and 1280 columns .i want split it into 2 array by 19 rows and 70% of columns for train and 30% of columns for test.and this columns select randomly.my code is in python.please help me.thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited to include randomised shuffle*

You can use [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to slice arrays into your desired shape and [`numpy.random.shuffle()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) to obtain randomiced array indices.

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

# create example data
num_cols, num_rows = 10, 3
arr = np.array([[f'{row}_{col}' for col in range(num_cols)] for row in range(num_rows)])

# create a list of random indices
random_cols = list(range(arr.shape[1]))
np.random.shuffle(random_cols)

# calculate truncation index as 70% of total number of columns
truncation_index = int(arr.shape[1] * 0.7)

# use arrray slicing to extract two sub_arrays
train_array = arr[:, random_cols[:truncation_index]]
test_array = arr[:, random_cols[truncation_index:]]

print(f'arr: \n{arr} \n')
print(f'train array: \n{train_array} \n')
print(f'test array: \n{test_array} \n')
```

With output

```
arr: 
[['0_0' '0_1' '0_2' '0_3' '0_4' '0_5' '0_6' '0_7' '0_8' '0_9']
 ['1_0' '1_1' '1_2' '1_3' '1_4' '1_5' '1_6' '1_7' '1_8' '1_9']
 ['2_0' '2_1' '2_2' '2_3' '2_4' '2_5' '2_6' '2_7' '2_8' '2_9']] 

train array: 
[['0_5' '0_8' '0_0' '0_7' '0_6' '0_1' '0_4']
 ['1_5' '1_8' '1_0' '1_7' '1_6' '1_1' '1_4']
 ['2_5' '2_8' '2_0' '2_7' '2_6' '2_1' '2_4']] 

test array: 
[['0_3' '0_9' '0_2']
 ['1_3' '1_9' '1_2']
 ['2_3' '2_9' '2_2']]
```

Comment: thank you.but I want the columns to be randomly selected, not in order